# Inject custom logic into Python package

Tags: python

Say package `A` contains a function `process(input)` that takes some input, does computation, and returns a result.

Is it possible for another function in package `B` to do something like `B.patchPackageA()` and modify/add logic to package `A`'s `process(input)` to do something extra?

For example, say package `A`'s `process(input)` does the following:

```py
def process(input: str):
    return input.upper()
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
B.patchPackageA()
```

and then if I were to call `A.process("hello world!")`, it would do something like:

```
def process(input: str):
    print("Modified logic")
    return input.upper()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit your tags to use the proper `python` tag rather than the `python-3.x` tag, which is reserved for questions that specifically apply to python 3, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the use case things might differ but I guess you could just create a decorator that adds the extra logic and create a wrapper function in package B with this decorator. Something like:

in A:

```
def process(input: str):
    return input.upper()
```

in B:

```
from A import process

def extra_logic(func):    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Modified logic")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)    
    return wrapper

@extra_logic
def updated_process(input: str):
    return process(input)

updated_process('bla')

Out:
Modified logic
'BLA'
```

This is slightly different to the use case you described. You won't be able to directly modify the behavior of `A.process()` because it is compiled when package import is run and from that point on, you're dealing with a compiled object in memory. So you will need to create a wrapper in `B` that adds extra logic and call that wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`A.py`:

```py
def process(input: str):
    return input.upper()
```

`B.py`:

```py
import A


def patchPackageA():
    def process(input: str):
        print("Modified logic")
        return input.upper()

    A.process = process
```

`test_1.py`:

```py
import A
import B

print("Check point 1")
print(A.process("Hello"))
print("Check point 2")
B.patchPackageA()
print("Check point 3")
print(A.process("Hello"))
print("Check point 4")
```

```bash
python3 test_1.py
```

Output:

```
Check point 1
HELLO
Check point 2
Check point 3
Modified logic
HELLO
Check point 4
```

It works the same way if B wants to set a module variable in package A.

---

However, note that if you `import process from A`, this won't work.

`test_2.py`

```py
from A import process
import B

print("Check point 1")
print(process("Hello"))
print("Check point 2")
B.patchPackageA()
print("Check point 3")
print(process("Hello"))
print("Check point 4")
```

```bash
python3 test_2.py
```

Output:

```
Check point 1
HELLO
Check point 2
Check point 3
HELLO
Check point 4
```